# Using CRS, DEM and Shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, dem

I have a DEM of a region [(metadata here)](https://imgur.com/a/AuW41) that I got from converting 16 las files using pointcloudviz. Now I have that loaded up in QGIS, and I have a shapefile I made from a hiking trip in that same area ([metadata here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W3SW.jpg). When I add both layers, the coordinates of the dem ranges in the 1000s (presumably meters) while the shapefile is in lon/lat.

I am somewhat aware of CRS, but changing both layer's CRS and the project CRS to the same thing doesn't really help (but I have no idea what I'm doing here). I've tried toggling OTF projection, and that changes things, but not in a useful way. Step by step instructions would be very helpful, since I know nothing about GIS.

I should note that my dem is in .vrt format and I have a large .vrt.ovr file and a small .vrt file. Idk the difference between these two but I have been loading the .vrt.ovr into qgis

EDIT: I think the issue is that I am not sure what CRS my dem is in. I think I have to figure that out before I can continue

Comment: The CRS of the DEM is surely wrong. You need to ask the data provider about the correct CRS (or look up at the website if you downloaded it).